# Why can't a server be controlled without a client?

Tags: php, node.js, server, client

Ok, in all the years servers have existed, you're telling me the best you can do is give me a crappy cron job if I want to make a script run every n seconds on my server? There MUST be a way built into a programming language or something that lets me run a function or script or something at intervals without a client having to send a request to the server. Is there any language that lets you do this? node js? How do big companies do server maintenance then? Why can php listen for requests constantly and webhooks but can't control the very thing it was designed to control without someone else sending a request?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a question or a rant. Also I think you might be confused on how the Client-Server architectures are supposed to work.

Comment: "a way built into a programming language or something that lets me run a function or script or something at intervals" - you mean a loop? Yes, most programming languages have that

Comment: infinite loops for the win! `while(true){ // loopity loop! }`

Comment: You seem upset.

Comment: won't infinite loops just break the server?

Comment: @E.SK Sometimes infinite loops are what's keeping the server alive. A server like nginx or Node.js is based on the concept of an event loop. And that loop is infinite. If it wasn't then the server would stop serving requests and *that* would break the server.

Comment: @rsp so you're saying it keeps reloading the script over and over? I thought the parts of the script that need to be constantly checking are 'extracted' by the platform running it, and a 'port' is opened to listen for that. Also, how am I meant to start an infinite loop on a server in php without an inital request? that defeats the purpose of this question.

Comment: @E.SK "Also, how am I meant to start an infinite loop on a server in php without an inital request? that defeats the purpose of this question." - see my updated answer. I explain how to do that.

Comment: "Why can PHP listen for requests..."  PHP doesn't listen for requests. A webserver listens for requests and forks off PHP to process it. Web servers and maintenance processes run as background services.

Comment: "crappy cron jobs"? So you think server admins make a sacrifice of unicorn blood to the server Gods? If cron jobs were never invented then they would have simply named them norc jobs with the same exact internals. Unless you get your own VPS then a shared hosting provider is not going to be stupid enough to allow just any wazoo to set up scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't a server be controlled without a client?

It can. A server may respond to the requests sent by the client but it can also do other things.

> Ok, in all the years servers have existed, you're telling me the best you can do is give me a crappy cron job if I want to make a script run every n seconds on my server?

I don't know who said you that but that is simply not true. Even a shell script can do that.

> There MUST be a way built into a programming language or something that lets me run a function or script or something at intervals without a client having to send a request to the server.

There must be and there is. See below for examples.

> Is there any language that lets you do this?

Yes, there are many such languages. For example JavaScript had `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` since something like 1995.

> node js?

Yes, Node.js can do that and many other things. Since you asked specifically about Node.js - here are soem of the modules that you can use  for that:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron-job
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-crontab
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/periodic-task
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-polling
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeplan
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/later
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda

In fact there are many more modules that handle scheduled tasks.

> How do big companies do server maintenance then?

There are many ways to do that, including the ones mentioned above. Sometimes they use cron, sometimes they use webhooks and other RPC to orchestrate large numbers of servers and initiate various tasks, sometimes the servers are doing it themselves. You can use stream, queue or pub/sub services in some cases to manage more complex scenarios.

> Why can php listen for requests constantly and webhooks but can't control the very thing it was designed to control without someone else sending a request?

Because PHP is not a standalone server. You can think of what you write in PHP as a kind of request handlers. And you need requests for the request handlers to, well, handle the requests.

In contrast, programs written in Node are standalone programs that keep running and can do what they want and when they want, and they just happen to respond to requests from the client. PHP scripts, on the other hand, are not standalone long-running programs but they are invoked by a server like Apache or nginx on every request to a specific route that is handled by a specific PHP script, and then the script runs, does its job of serving this single request and finishes, only to be invoked later for another request if it happens.

Now, if you want to have a periodically running PHP script then you can do something like this: put the script on the server, it can respond only to localhost if you want, and test it if it runs every time that you do e.g. a POST request to `http://localhost:1234/script.php` and if it does you can do few things to make it run every n seconds as you wanted:

(1) You can put `curl -X POST http://localhost:1234/script.php` in crontab

(2) You can make a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
  curl -X POST http://localhost:1234/script.php
  sleep 10
done
```

(3) You can make a Node program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const request = require('request');
setInterval(() => request.post('http://localhost:1234/script.php'), 10000);
```

(4) You can use any other language that lets you run standalone programs.

This is one way to have a PHP script that you want to be run periodically.

Comment: you haven't really answered my question. Javascript is client side. I need to essentially do what a cron job does, by running the php every x seconds, but without a cron job. I do not believe that big companies rely on cron jobs, it doesn't seem legit enough.

Comment: essentially, is there a server side language that does not have to act as just a request handler as you have described php as

Comment: @E.SK Node.js is server-side and it's JavaScript. See: https://nodejs.org/

Comment: ok, so then why can node js control the server at intervals but php cannot? (without a client request)

Comment: @E.SK Because programs written in Node are standalone programs that keep running and can do what they want and when they want, and they just happen to respond to requests from the client. PHP scripts, on the other hand, are not standalone long-running programs but they are invoked by a server like Apache or nginx on every request to a specific route that is handled by a specific PHP script, and then the script runs, does its job of serving this single request and finishes, only to be invoked later for another request.

Comment: I see now. Thanks.